# Can we implement Rust like Traits using Kotlin Interfaces

Tags: kotlin

Can we implement Rust like Traits and generic Traits using Kotlin Interfaces?

Also is there any way of using fn(&self) like construct in Kotlin class/interface default function implementations?

Can some examples be shown please?

Thanks

Comment: If you explain what these constructs do in Rust I can tell you if this is possible in Kotlin.

Comment: _Some_ of things done with Rust traits can be done in Kotlin, others not. If you want answers and examples for each, that's a rather huge list.

Comment: I understand about that huge list. What I wanted to figure out that (1) whether a self/Self kind of thing as available in Rust traits and implemented structs is also available in Kotlin. Ex: Trait HasArea in https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/book/traits.html (2) is it possible to declare Associated Type Traits in Kotlin (3) Fully Qualified Syntax for Disambiguation: Calling Methods with the Same Name (the Pilot/Wizard/Human) example in https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html. Thanks

Comment: I could actually do (1) and (2) mentioned above in my comment. But not sure about (3), as a call like  ((person as Wizard)::fly)() does not print the Wizard::fly implementation. [CODE] interface BaseIntF{
    fun fly()
}
interface Pilot : BaseIntF{
    override fun fly() { println("This is your captain speaking.") }
}

interface Wizard : BaseIntF {
    override fun fly() { println("Up!") }
}

class Human : Pilot, Wizard {
    override fun fly() {
        println("*waving arms furiously*")        
    }
}[/CODE]Thanks.

Comment: fun main() {
    val person = Human()

    (person::fly)()
    ((person as Wizard)::fly)() //Not giving desired result like Rust .. prints the person implementation only }

Comment: Also tried this way of calling (person<Wizard>::fly)(), which says "Left hand side of callable reference matches expression syntax reserved for future releases". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Rust, I'm referrring to these two videos as for what you're talking about, [generic traits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URDlIAsyLP4) and [&self](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sI-GzVSYic) explaination.

In kotlin you'd implement them using interfaces and classes as you've guessed.

An example of that is:

```kotlin
interface GenericTrait { // Same as traits
    // <T:Any> just makes method to be called for non-null values, if you use <T>, you can pass null as well
    fun <T: Any> method(value: T)
}

class TraitImpl : GenericTrait { // Same as structs
    val isDisabled = Random.nextBoolean() // instance variable

    // you can access instance parameter using the this or even not using it at all as in below
    override fun <T: Any> method(value: T) {
        println("Type of value is ${value::class}, and the value is $value. I am $isDisabled")
        // or explicitly call ${this.isDisabled}, both are the same
    }
}

fun main() {
    TraitImpl().method("Hello")
    TraitImpl().method(23)

    TraitImpl().apply { // this: TraitImpl
        method(23)
        method(Unit)
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Type of value is class kotlin.String, and the value is Hello. I am true
Type of value is class kotlin.Int, and the value is 23. I am true
Type of value is class kotlin.Int, and the value is 23. I am false
Type of value is class kotlin.Unit, and the value is kotlin.Unit. I am false
```

You can extract implementation outside if you want as an extension function just like you do in Rust.

```kotlin
interface GenericTrait {
    val isDisabled: Boolean
}

class TraitImpl : GenericTrait {
    override val isDisabled = Random.nextBoolean()
}

// define methods out of class declaration
fun <T: Any> GenericTrait.method(value: T) {
    println("Type of value is ${value::class}, and the value is $value. I am $isDisabled")
}
```

Comment: @Prana, welcome, does this solves your problem or more help is needed?

Comment: How the extension method should be called from another function, say, from the main()? Thanks.

Comment: @Prana you can call it with an instance of implementation. `TraitImpl().method(...)`, there's no new keyword in kotlin, `TraitImpl()` will create a new instance of TraitImpl

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your time.